# Why does Arabic not display correctly in wkhmltopdf?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wkhtmltopdf

What's the problem with following script? I am using wkhtmltopdf to convert HTML to PDF. It does not show arabic fonts correctly in the PDF output, while English fonts display fine. How can I get rid of this problem? I have tried several scripts and made several modifications, but the problem is still there.

```
private void WritePDF(string HTML)
            {
                string inFileName, outFileName;
                Process p;
               // System.IO.StreamWriter stdin;
                ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();


                inFileName = Session.SessionID + ".htm";

               outFileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/PDF"), "test.pdf");
               // outFileName = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "temp\\" + Session.SessionID + ".pdf";
                psi.UseShellExecute = false;

                psi.FileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/PDFConverter"), "wkhtmltopdf.exe");
                psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
                psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                psi.RedirectStandardError = true;


                psi.Arguments = "-q -n - " + outFileName;
                p = Process.Start(psi);

                try
                {
                    StreamWriter stdin = new StreamWriter(p.StandardInput.BaseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                    stdin = p.StandardInput;
                    stdin.AutoFlush = true;
                  //  byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(HTML);
                   // HTML = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
                    stdin.Write(HTML);
                    stdin.Close();

                    byte[] fileContent = null;
                    if (p.WaitForExit(15000))
                    {
                        FileStream fs = new FileStream(outFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                        fileContent = new byte[(int)fs.Length];

                        //read the content
                        fs.Read(fileContent, 0, (int)fs.Length);

                        //close the stream
                        fs.Close();
                        Response.Clear();
                        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=pg.pdf");
                        Response.BinaryWrite(fileContent);
                        Response.End();

                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    p.Close();
                    p.Dispose();
                }



            }
```

Comment: Can you post the top section of the html you are trying to convert? its probably just the matter of declearing the charset..  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: also prior to ending the `Response` have your tried `Response.Flush();` I would also format the 
`Responsde.AppendHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.pdf", somefilename))` if the file name is expected to change

Comment: Yes its already in my head section,Actually I am passing string to wkhtmltopdf instead of url

Comment: Method man I am not getting you can you modify the code

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are using the wrong encoding; ASCII does not support Arabic as far as I know. You can check for a proper encoding [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encodinginfo.getencoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or if you want to perform encoding conversion on files check [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e17f99a9-f4fa-49a6-82da-0c73d930224d/encoding-in-arabic). Hope that helps!

Or, you can change your

```
 StreamWriter stdin = new StreamWriter(p.StandardInput.BaseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
```

to this if you want to use Windows-1256 encoding for Arabic:

```
StreamWriter stdin = new StreamWriter(p.StandardInput.BaseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(1256));
```

or to this if you want to use ISO-8859-6 Arabic:

```
StreamWriter stdin = new StreamWriter(p.StandardInput.BaseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(28596));
```

If you want to use any other encoding tables, check the first link I have provided for you. *Hint: Read the commented table there.*

Comment: @testuser what is the original encoding of your html ?

Comment: I am using this <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> in actual code